# Struggling to find updates for WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Afternoon all, 
Im having a bit of an issue finding updates for WSS 3 (I Know its old but Im stuck with it)

I have 2 servers one is on version 12.0.0.6665 and the other is on 12.0.0.6608

The problem is that I need them to both be on the same version but cant find an update to get 12.0.0.6608 up to 12.0.0.6665 windows update isnt bringing up any updates and I cant find any online... any thoughts? Hints?

Thanks